# Inserting data using one to many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem about my project. I am using Entity Framework Code First in my project.

Here is problem: I have two models that have one to many relationship between them.

Employee Model:

```
{
    public int employeeId { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string surname { get; set; }

    public int tel_no { get; set; }

    public string fullname
    {
        get
        {
            return name + " " + surname;
        }
    }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual Manager Manager { get; set; }
}
```

Department Model:

```
{
    public int departmentId { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
}
```

First, I am inserting a department data to department table succesfully. After then, I want to insert an employee data to employee table. When I am inserting employee data to relevant table, also I am getting department data from department table to make a relation between employee and data.

But when I click save button, the data I got from department table is being inserted to department table again and there are two same data in department table.

Here is my view:

```
<div class = "form-group">
        <label class = "control-label col-md-3"> Adı </label>

        <div class = "col-md-8">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3"> Soyadı </label>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3"> Telefon Numarası </label>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tel_no, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tel_no, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3"> Bölümü </label>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Department.name, ViewBag.Departments as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control dropdown-toggle" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3"> Yöneticisi </label>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Manager.fullname, ViewBag.Managers as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control dropdown-toggle" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Manager.fullname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is controller:

```
// GET: Admin/CreateEmployee
    public ActionResult CreateEmployee()
    {
        var nameOfManagers = (from manager in database.Employee select manager);
        var nameOfDepartments = (from department in database.Department select department);

        ViewBag.Managers = new SelectList(nameOfManagers, "fullname", "fullname");
        ViewBag.Departments = new SelectList(nameOfDepartments, "name", "name");

        return View();
    }

    // POST: Admin/CreateEmployee
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(employee.Manager != null)
            {
                String[] manager_info = employee.Manager.fullname.Split(' ');

                for (int i = 0; i < manager_info.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    employee.Manager.name += manager_info[i] + " ";
                }

                employee.Manager.surname = manager_info[manager_info.Length - 1];
            }

            database.Employee.Add(employee);
            database.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(employee);
    }
```

And last thing is screenshot of the running project:

[Showing of Department and Employee Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDRI1.jpg)

I could not solve this problem. If you help me, I am so glad.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see where you get the Department for the Employee you're creating... And, as a suggestion, call your `Get` method `GetEmployee`, so you don't have two `CreateEmployee` methods that do different things. Anyway a common problem is adding a related entity that isn't attached to the same (or any) context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're literally creating a new department. By posting to `Department.name`, the model binder is newing up an instance of `Department` on the `Employee` and then setting the `name` property of that instance. However, no other properties are being set, like, importantly, the id. So when you save the employee, the department, which has no id, looks new to Entity Framework, and it creates that as well.

What you *should* be doing is posting to a property on `Employee` that doesn't cause an instance of `Department` to be created. Essentially, you have two choices:

1. If you have an explicit foreign key property on `Employee` like `DepartmentId`, then post to *that*. If the foreign key property is filled in and the navigation property, `Department` is null, Entity Framework will backfilled it with the Department matching `DepartmentId` from the database.
2. If you don't have an explicit foreign key property, i.e. you just have the `Department` property and are relying on Entity Framework's convention-based approach to creating a column in the table automatically to track that relationship, then you *must* use a view model. Let me say that again: you absolutely cannot use your entity directly. You'll need to create something like:

   ```
   public class EmployeeViewModel
   {
       // other employee properties you want to edit

       public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Then, once you get to your post action, you'll need to map the values from this view model to your actual entity, and namely, use the posted value for `DepartmentId` to lookup the right department from the database in order to set the `Department` property on your employee.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your suggestions on my project.